# The "gig" question shoud be reopened

Tags: support

I think the following [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/141875/the-meaning-of-gig-here) is interesting and the meaning OP is looking for is not so intuitive as one might assume. 
Gig has a number of different definitions and the one about a temporary job is not among the first, the second or even the third more common meanings suggested by most dictionaries.
It is a reasonable question and it deserves a proper answer.

Answer (score 5):

Which dictionaries did the author look in and what did they find? Some effort should be expended on the part of the author to answer the question before posting it. If I search for *define "[gig economy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gig-economy)"* I get:

> noun, Informal.
>   1. an economic sector consisting of part-time, temporary, and freelance jobs:
>   *rapid growth of the online gig economy.*

It's fine if a learner can't understand that definition, but they need to explain why the dictionary didn't help answer their question, not just use this community as a dictionary look-up service.

I went ahead and edited the question to include a comment by the author and reopened it.

Comment: Thanks, I think the question may be of help also to future users.